# Why `bash -c "$cmd"` return current date here?

Tags: bash

**Context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253784/15603477**

```
cmd='printf "%s\n" "$(date -d "$variable" +%c)"'
echo ${variable}
```

returns `2010-09-08 12:34:56`

`echo "$cmd"` returns `printf "%s\n" $(date -d "$variable")`
`echo "${cmd}"` returns `printf "%s\n" $(date -d "$variable")`

run the following command `bash -c "$cmd"`
then as the answer shows:

```
Fri
Dec
24
00:00:00
IST
2021
```

Here is what found:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858381/what-does-bash-c-do
- https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash

> Read and execute commands from the first non-option argument command_string, then exit. If there are arguments after the command_string, the first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters. The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

---

My question is regarding last command `bash -c "$cmd"`, The output: **Today** (as now is 2021-Dec-24) is come from where?

--update:
I checked https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#eval, https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html
The following quote is what i found about `eval`

> eval [arg ...]
> The args are read and concatenated together into a single
> command.  This command is then read and executed by the
> shell, and its exit status is returned as the value of
> eval.  If th

Comment: Because you are not echo/printing the variable but use the content as the command? Not even sure what your doubt is.

Comment: Maybe `help eval` can give you some insight as well, if the quoting thing is confusing to you.

Comment: @TomYan, I already check manual section about `eval` seems not reference about date.

Comment: The output of `echo "$cmd"` reveals something different (missing 2 double quotes) from what you allegedly assigned it to above. Try after `cmd='printf "%s\n" "$(date -d "$variable" +%c)"'` again

Comment: You'll also need `export variable` if you want the `$variable` variable of the current shell to be exported to the environment, for the new `bash` instance you execute to import it again as its own `$variable` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bash -c "$cmd"` shell code executes the `bash` command with 3 arguments:

1. `bash`
2. `-c`
3. the contents of the `$cmd` variable

Invoking a shell like that is the standard way (every shell does that, not just `bash`¹) to have it interpret  the code in the third argument.

Here, you say that `$cmd` was initialised as:

```
cmd='printf "%s\n" "$(date -d "$variable" +%c)"'
```

But the output of your `echo "$cmd"` reveals it was rather assigned as:

```
cmd='printf "%s\n" $(date -d "$variable" +%c)'
```

So the shell code that that new `bash` invocation will interpret is:

```
printf "%s\n" $(date -d "$variable" +%c)
```

Now, since it's a new `bash` interpreter being started, that `$variable` will not have been assigned there. If you had ran `bash -uc` (same as `bash -o nounset -c`) instead of `-c`, you'd have gotten:

```
bash: line 1: variable: unbound variable
```

Without the `nounset` option, unset variables are expanded as if they were empty, so the `date` command is called with these arguments:

1. `date`
2. `-d`
3. an empty argument
4. `+%c`

`-d` is not a standard `date` option. In the case of GNU `date`, it is used to specify an input date. When that input date is empty, that's equivalent to `date -d 0` or `date -d 00:00:00`, that is today at 00:00:00 in the morning.

Now, because `$(date...)` is not quoted and is in list context (in arguments to a `printf` command), it is subject to split+glob. The splitting part breaks the output of date on the characters of `$IFS` which by default contains space, tab and newline in bash, so you see one separate argument being generated for `printf` for each blank-separated word in the output of `date` (the globbing part doesn't do anything here as there's no wildcard character in that output of `date`).

So with `date` outputting: `Fri Dec 24 00:00:00 IST 2021`, that results in `printf` being invoked with these arguments:

1. `printf`
2. `%s\n`
3. `Fri`
4. `Dec`
5. `00:00:00`
6. `IST`
7. `2021`

And `printf` will reuse the `%s\n` format as many times as possible to consume all the arguments, ending up printing all of them on separate lines.

Now, if you want that new `bash` instance to *inherit* the `$variable` of the shell that invokes it, you can `export` that variable to the environment, either for all future invocations of every command with:

```
export variable
bash -c "$cmd"
```

(`printenv variable`,  `perl -E 'say $ENV{variable}'`... will also see it).

Or just for that one invocation of `bash`³ with:

```
(export variable; exec bash -c "$cmd")
```

Or:

```
variable=$variable bash -c "$cmd"
```

In

```
eval "$cmd"
```

It is the current shell that is told  to interpret the code in `$cmd`, and as that's the shell invocation in which you had assigned `$variable`, it will be able to access its contents, so you don't need to export it to the environment.

---

<sup>¹ that's also the case of some interpreters of some other languages that can't really be seen as shell languages, like `python`. While some others use different options like `sed -e 'sed code'`, `perl -e 'perl code'`, `php -r 'php code'`... or no option at all: `awk 'awk code'`, `sed 'sed code'`</sup>

<sup>² and with `$0` set to `bash`, and with the list of positional parameters empty here.</sup>

<sup>³ and the commands that that `bash` instance will execute itself</sup>

Comment: Can you help me with this > https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683760/what-does-paste-d-mean-in-this-context-also-confused-with-ifs

Answer (score 3):

The command defined by the `$cmd` variable references a variable called `$variable`. Given that `$cmd` is passed to a new shell invocation in another process, at the point that `$cmd` is executed this variable is not set. The resulting invocation to get the date is therefore `date -d "" +%c`, which returns the current date.

From a coding perspective, storing commands in variables is bad practice. You *will* end up with a quoting nightmare sooner or later. Use variables for data and functions for code.

```
cmd() {
    local v=$1
    printf "%s\n" "$(date -d "$v" +%c)"'
}

variable="2010-09-08 12:34:56"
cmd "$variable"
```

Finally, unless you have good reason, always ensure your variables are inside double quotes when you use them. (`echo $variable` is poor; `echo "$variable"` is better; `printf "%s\n" "$variable"` is best.)